# Chain Email about how smart our brains are

Tags: python, append

So i'm trying to reproduce in Python something i've seen everywhere, is turning this:

A university is an institution of higher education and research
which grants academic degrees in a variety of subjects and
provides both undergraduate education and postgraduate education
The word university is derived from the Latin universitas
magistrorum et scholarium which roughly means community of teachers
and scholars

into this:

A utisreviny is an ioitutitsnn of hehgir eoitacudn and rcraeseh
wcihh gtnars aimedacc deerges in a vteiray of stcejbus and
pedivors btoh utaudargredne eoitacudn and ptaudargtsoe eoitacudn
The wrod utisreviny is devired form the Litan uatisrevins
murortsigam et suiralohcm wcihh rlhguoy mnaes ctinummoy of trehcaes
and sralohcs

i'm trying to do it simply, taking in the `sys.stdin` and i want to take the first letter, then what is between the first and last, then the last. I've been playing with string slicing, and here's what i've done:

```html
import sys

def main():
    new_file = []
    for line in sys.stdin:
        for word in line:
            if len(word) == 1:
                new_file += word
        else:
            new_file += word[0]+word[::-1]+word[-1]
    return new_file

print main()
```

It keeps printing every individual letter to my `new_file` list, and i don't want that.

Comment: You want `for word in line.split():`

Comment: that made it reverse the whole input. `['A', 'r', 'h', 'c', 'r', 'a', 'e', 's', 'e', 'r', 'h', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'n', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'i', 't', 'a', 'c', 'u', 'd
', 'e', 'n', 'u', 's', 'a', 't', 'i', 's', 'r', 'e', 'v', 'i', 'n', 'u', 's', 't', 's', 'r', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'a', 'e', 't', 's', 
's', 's', 'r', 'a', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'c', 's', 's']`

Comment: You also want `new_file += word[0] + word[-1:1:-1] + word[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

`for word in line:` is looping over the *characters* in `line` -- that's how looping over a string **works**!  (Perhaps the #1 cause of bugs by Python newbies).

You may want `for word in line.split():` but this will ignore whitespace and punctuation, which you might want to preserve.

You might go for regular expressions, e.g...:

```
def smurk(mo):
    w = mo.group(0)
    if len(w) < 4: return w
    return w[0] + w[-2:0:-1] + w[-1]

...

line = re.sub(r'\w+', smurk, line)

...
```

You could optimize more by only matching sequences of 4+ word-characters, but if you're no a RE wizard you're best advised to keep you REs simple, and this one sure is: "one or more word-characters".

The substitution function `smurk` gets a match object as an arg, gets the word from it (`.group(0)` == all that the RE matched), avoids unneeded work for any word of fewer than 4 characters, and does the deed (with the right slicing, which yours wasn't, quite) for words of 4+ characters.  The `re` module does the rest for you:-).

Comment: so how do i grab the whole word and slice it?